# How to identify the cause of an API call repeating itself in Angular JS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, api, http

I am having an issue with AngularJS where when an order is placed, the api is called multiple times, but only reaches success() once. This is the code in question:

```
function placeOrder(cart) {
            var serviceUrl = getOrderUrl();
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            $http({ method: 'POST', url: serviceUrl, data: cart })
                .success(function (data, status, hearers, confing) {
                    deferred.resolve(data);
                })
                .error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                    deferred.reject(status);
                });
            return deferred.promise;
        }
```

I removed logging from the example, but in my code placeOrder() is called multiple times which calls the API multiple times, but success() is only reached once, and error() is never reached. After success() is reached the duplicate API calls stop.

In my most recent example the first two were back to back, and the third one was 7 minutes later when it finally hit success().

What could be causing this? Is Angular timing out and repeating the call or something?

From my research I see success() and error() are depreciated. Was that because of an issue similar to mine?

Comment: You say multiple times. Is it only two times? Most likely the first is a CORS request and the verb is actually an `OPTIONS` request.

Comment: What do you see in your browser's DevTools' Network window?

Comment: No clue, customers are reporting the issue and I just have logs to work with.

Comment: Where are the logs?

Comment: Multiple repeat requests to your Orders endpoint shouldn't be a problem if you designed it to be idempotent - so why not just make it idempotent and then stop worrying about it? (Granted, you'll need clients/consumers to handle idempotency tokens if request-identity cannot be derived from the request, but that's shouldn't be a major problem)